# antd forms - complex child elements of <Form.Item>

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

I have a antd form like this:

```js
return(   
   <Form
    {...layout}
    form={form}
    onFinish={onFinish}
   >
    <Form.Item
        label="Bezeichnung"
        name="name"
        initialValue={resource ? resource.name : ""}
        rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Bitte Bezeichnung eingeben.' }]}
    >
        <Input />
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item
        label="Farbe"
        name="color"
        initialValue={resource ? resource.color : undefined}
    >
        <Input />
    </Form.Item>
    <ColorPickerButton 
        onColorChange={(color) => {
            form.setFieldsValue({
                color: color.hex
            });
        }}
    />
    </Form>
);
```

As you can see  here, i hav an extra button (independenly of the form) which acts as a color-picker. The chosen color is then used with

```js
form.setFieldsValue({
    color: color.hex
});
```

My question is now: Is there a more convenient way of putting together the `<Input />` component with the `<ColorPickerButton />`component to use it that way:

```js
    <Form.Item
        label="Farbe"
        name="color"
        initialValue={resource ? resource.color : undefined}
    >
        <ColorPickerInput />
    </Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want some kinds of "auto binding" between `Form.Item` and `ColorPickerInput`? You can try to pass `form` and `name` to `ColorPickerInput` component, and call `form.setFieldsValue({[name]: value})` within `ColorPickerButton.onColorChange` to update it.

Comment: this line --> form.setFieldsValue({[name]: value}) was very helpful. Many thanks